# Redisson.create failing with IllegalArgumentException: hostname can't be null

Tags: redis, redisson

Trying to connect to Redis (on Docker) using Redisson... simple stuff..

`Config config = new Config();
config.useSingleServer().setAddress("redis://192.168.99.100:6379");
RedissonClient redisson = Redisson.create(config);` //line 3

But I am getting this error (at line 3) - am I missing something ?

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: hostname can't be null at java.net.InetSocketAddress.checkHost(InetSocketAddress.java:149)
at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:216)
at org.redisson.client.RedisClient.<init>(RedisClient.java:105)
at org.redisson.connection.MasterSlaveConnectionManager.createClient(MasterSlaveConnectionManager.java:326)
at org.redisson.connection.MasterSlaveConnectionManager.createClient(MasterSlaveConnectionManager.java:314)
at org.redisson.connection.SingleEntry.setupMasterEntry(SingleEntry.java:47)
at org.redisson.connection.MasterSlaveConnectionManager.initEntry(MasterSlaveConnectionManager.java:263)
at org.redisson.connection.MasterSlaveConnectionManager.init(MasterSlaveConnectionManager.java:231)
    at org.redisson.connection.MasterSlaveConnectionManager.<init>(MasterSlaveConnectionManager.java:159)
    at org.redisson.connection.SingleConnectionManager.<init>(SingleConnectionManager.java:48)
    at org.redisson.config.ConfigSupport.createConnectionManager(ConfigSupport.java:168)
    at org.redisson.Redisson.<init>(Redisson.java:111)
    at org.redisson.Redisson.create(Redisson.java:151)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `config.useSingleServer().setAddress("192.168.99.100:6379")` was the solution. no need to prepend `redis://`

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code to Connect :

```
Config config = new Config();
config.useSingleServer().setAddress("192.168.99.100:6379");
RedissonClient redisson = Redisson.create(config);
```

Comment: thanks.. but I am using a standalone setup and I found the issue.